# Using google custom search engine to download pics

Tags: google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

I am trying to download some pictures with google custom search.

I can return the url for the first 10 pics. But when I expand the range to 20 pics, there are some errors.

```
#initialize service
service = build("customsearch", "v1",
               developerKey=key) 


# search for image
res = service.cse().list(
    q= "apples",
    cx= cx,
    searchType='image',
    num=10,
    fileType='jpg/png',
    safe= 'off'
).execute()
#print the result
if res["items"] is None:
    print("No result")
else:
    for item in res['items']:
        print("Title is:",item['title'], "link is:", item['link'])
```

The code works when num = 10, but fails when num exceeds 10.
Anyone can help me with this?
What should I do to make it return more than 10 urls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'num' can only take a maximum value of 10.
In order to get more results, you'll need to paginate using the 'start' parameter.
For example, if 'num' is 10, then start=11 would give the second page of results.

See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list